# Ontario HST rebate: Canada Student Loan debt in default. Can they take my transition rebate?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, student-loan

I don't owe the Ontario government anything - not even student loans - but I do have a defaulted Canada Student Loan in default. Can they take my transition rebate?

Answer (score 1):

Good Question.  I would guess "No" as the transition rebate is Provincial, and administered by the province directly.  CSL garnishments are administered by CRA, which is why they can take your tax refund and GST credits.  I doubt the administration is set up for them to reach into you provincial benefits.

However, the prudent thing to do would be to apply the HST cheque to the CSL.